# Is there a way to confirm if a POST request was actually sent through a proxy using the Python Requests library?

Tags: python, http, python-requests, http-proxy, socks

I have a list of SOCKS5 proxies that I randomly choose from and use send a POST request, with the Python library Requests. The problem is that I don't know how to confirm if the proxy was actually used or if it used my home IP, since succeeding with sending a GET request with the same proxy can't guarantee that the proxy was actually used for the POST request (in my experience).

I have tried to find a header in the response object that tells me the sender's IP but I don't see it.
I can test GET requests' origin IP with online services like httpbin but I couldn't find the same for a POST request.

```py
def register_account(captcha_response, email, password):
    proxies = random_proxy()    # Dict format: {'http': socks5://ip, 'https': socks5://ip}
    try:
        response = requests.post(url=register_url, proxies=proxies, timeout=(5, 20), data={
            'email1': email,
            'onlyOneEmail': 1,
            'password1': password,
            'onlyOnePassword': 1,
            'day': '01',
            'month': '01',
            'year': 1990
            'agree_email': 1,
            'g-recaptcha-response': captcha_response,
            'create-submit': 'create'
        })
        return True
    except:
        print(f'Error: {sys.exc_info()[0]}')
        return False
```

I'm open to suggestions that doesn't involve the Request library as well.

Comment: Only one way to find out in my opinion. Set up a server with a POST enabled endpoint somewhere and try it out. It's probably the only way to know for sure

Comment: You can block all the IP apart from the proxy IP with a firewall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using this service to test my POST request: https://webhook.site
You can check the IP of the sender using this. The request doesn't have to have the correct fields either.